# What is a good standard practice to find a distinct regex patterns from a single field in a table?

Tags: c#, javascript, regex, vb6, sql-server-2000

I'm looking for a standard approach to generate all the unique patterns that can occur in a single field in an sql 2000-2008r2 table.  Is there a simple tool that will generate all the different static patterns.  Also is there a name for a distinct regular expression pattern.  I'm trying to do this t-sql, but will also perform this in either c#, or vb6, or even javascript.  I've noticed that apostrophes can come into play, as well as : or other text.  Is there a good way to detect when a user puts in various combinations?

\d{1,1}\d{1,1}\d{1,1}[.]\d{1,1}  would be the same pattern for 111.10  or 201.90.

If I have other patterns such as "Refund"  I want to see something like [A-z]{6,6}.  Is there a command or tool for Regular expression that would generate these distinct but static patterns, so that when a new pattern crops up, I can date and time stamp when it occurs and have it be validated.  When someone type 7 characters, I want the Patterns that were caught under Refund to now also accept the pattern for "Balance". [A-z]{6,7} is now acceptable and won't cause the user to be alerted after validation has occurred by an admin.

Thanks

Comment: We implemented CLR for this (though that won't work for SQL Server 2000). This is a good intro article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Comment: I think you are unlikely to find a standard approach for doing this mapping, in part because your rules are so arbitrary. Let's take two sets of strings that differ only in their last character. According to your example, if the strings are 111.1 and 111.2 they should map to the same regex. But if the strings are Refund and Refunx they should map to different regexes. So I think you're going to have to come up with these mapping rules yourself. But once you do, the writing the program to do the mapping and find the distinct patterns should be trivial.

Comment: I was looking more for a standard approach for doing this.  I'll modify the question. thx

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your question gets encountered enough to have a standard practice...

While it would be possible to analyze two regular expressions and deterimine if the are equivalent, I don't think anyone has actually done so and made the results available...

Comment: Analyzing whether two regular expressions are equivalent would be nice, but is not a prerequisite for generating regular expressions based on a set of examples.  Googling for "generate regular expression from examples" brings up 10.9M hits for me right now, so it's not like this is unexplored territory.  http://txt2re.com/ and (to a lesser extent) http://www.regexmagic.com/autogenerate.html look vaguely promising.

Comment: As altogether a different data point, SpamSieve for the Mac does amazing on-the-fly token generation for its Bayesian filter.  I actually got in touch with the author a few years ago, but his take on it was that he didn't use any particularly exciting algorithms or methods ... I'll see if I can find his email.